# Removing created control using code?

Tags: vb.net

Here is what I wrote:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub Label1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseHover
Dim Label2 As New Label
Label2.Location = New Point(158, 87)
Label2.Text = "lol"
Me.Controls.Add(Label2)
End Sub

Public Sub Label1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseLeave
Me.Controls.Remove(Label2)
End Sub
End Class
```

So, I wanted to create a new label when I get my mouse on the other one, and when I leave label with my mouse, I want that newly created control to disappear.
With this code, it says: "'Label2' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." Probably because Label2 is not actually in registry until I create it when I run the program. Can somebody help me then?

Comment: Does it need to be a new Label? Would it not be easier to have one there and simply make it visible when you mouse over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `Label2` is local to the Function it is declared in - this means you can only access it inside this function. You could use a variable at the module level (declare it private if you don't want to use it from other modules too). See the MSDN [Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is Scope. The declaration of Label2 is within the event handler for label1.mousehover, so it will not exist during label1.mouseleave's event handler.

You likely can better accomplish what you want by creating the label and setting it invisible, and then manipulating its visibility and text in your event handlers.